# Oracle FDW support in AWS

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds, postgres-fdw, oracle-fdw

I have an OLTP DB in Oracle and a downstream OLAP System in PostgreSQL on-premises. The data from Oracle is pumped into PostgreSQL using Oracle_FDW.

I am exploring the possibility of moving the PostgreSQL to AWS, but none of the RDS have Oracle_fdw capability. One way out is to install PG on an EC2 instance but that would leave some of the features like read-replica provided natively by AWS. Is there a better workaround?

Also is there a way to fetch the data in Oracle RDS from Postgres RDS in AWS?

Comment: Did anyone find the solution to this issue using RDS PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 1):

With PostgreSQL on Amazon RDS your choice of extensions is limited to the [extensions they explicitly support](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_PostgreSQL.html#PostgreSQL.Concepts.General.FeatureSupport.Extensions.101x). As far as I'm aware there's no way around this limitation.

Like you mentioned, the general option in this case would be to host PostgreSQL yourself on EC2 instead of RDS. You lose automatic backup/replication/management features, but you get the power and flexibility you need. This will certainly work but will require some leg work to replace what you're losing by not using RDS.

The only alternative to this I can think of is that you may be able to host a different (otherwise empty) PostgreSQL server with the oracle-fdw extension installed and use the postgres-fdw extension (which is supported by RDS) to proxy requests from your RDS hosted database, through your proxy PostgreSQL database, to your Oracle database and back. If the amount of data you're retrieving is substantial, or if the number of queries per minute is high this is probably a terrible idea. But it might be worth testing to see if it works for your use case.

I did a quick search around and I haven't been able to find any references to anyone actually layering foreign data wrappers like this but I also couldn't find anything in the manual or online saying it wasn't supported either. In theory it should work, but if you do try it make sure you thoroughly test it prior to using it to do anything important.

Comment: It should  work to "chain" FDEs like that, but it does not sound like a good idea.

Comment: I wholeheartedly agree. It was the only alternative that I could think of that would let you query an Oracle database from RDS. It'd be a sketchy proposition in a production system though.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle_FDW is now supported in recent versions - https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2021/07/amazon-rds-for-postgresql-supports-oracle-fdw-extension-for-accessing-data-in-oracle-databases/